# Label appears only after adding and removing cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, autolayout

I have a UITable with custom TableView cells.

The cell's contents are based on the segmented control ("Upcoming/Settled").
I have posted a screenshot with three images.

The first shows the cell as soon as the app is loaded. Next to the flame, it should have a number (100219). However, because the text on the left is very long, for some reason I the number is not drawn.

If I change the segmented control index, and bring some new cells (that have shorter-length text), the number appears.
Now, If I switch back to the cell with the long name I get the expected effect which is the name being shrinked to fit and the number drawn as well.
Any ideas how to get this to work as soon as the app is loaded?

Link to image that shows the issue:
[UITableViewCell - Autolayout - Label](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZWF7K.png)

Comment: In your xib file of your custom cell set the Horizontal Content Compression Resistance Priority of your number label higher than the one of the text label on the left of the flame. (so probably to 751) You can set the Content Compression Resistance by selecting your label and then go to the size inspector.

Comment: set both the content hugging and resistance horizontal property to 1000 for the number label.